# How to Get HTML Code of TextBox in Javascript when using HTMLEditorExtender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using HTMLEditorExtender ajax tool in my website. My data save into database in html format and I retrieve it in my project. Everything is working fine. but...
When I am trying to do  the same thing using jquery ajax I can't get HTML code of my content (with html tags). I am using this like to get TextBox value

```
var Value = $("[id*=txtContent]").val();
```

Let's say I have content "Hello My Name is Shaiwal **Tripathi**". I want to achieve this...

```
<p>Hello My Name is Shaiwal <b>Tripathi</b></p>
```

But I am getting plain text without any html tags

I had tried
`var Value = $("[id*=txtContent]").text();` and

```
var Value = $("[id*=txtContent]").html();
```

But not succeeded... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code

if your code like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditor" runat="server" Width="300" Height="200" />
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEditor">
</asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Try with below in javascript

```
$("#HtmlEditorExtender1_ExtenderContentEditable").innerHTML;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("HtmlEditorExtender1_ExtenderContentEditable").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link. You need to create an instance of HtmlEditorExtender and then you can get or set the value using jQuery.

[https://forums.asp.net/t/1784909.aspx?Get+Set+HtmlEditorExtender+content+via+javascript+or+jquery+](https://forums.asp.net/t/1784909.aspx?Get%20Set%20HtmlEditorExtender%20content%20via%20javascript%20or%20jquery%20)